# Converting sum of individual fraction to a combined fraction

Tags: fractions

I have following scenario.

I want this combined fraction $\frac{A+B+C}{X+Y+Z}$ But Some How I am a little unfortunate and  have results in the form of $\frac AX$, $\frac BY$ and $\frac CZ$.

How can I use this information to calculate the combined fraction?

Comment: Is this how the fraction should look like? I edited some of your text, so can you check whether everything is alright?

Comment: Yes Yes exactly like you suggested.

Comment: If you know the fractions then where is the problem?

Comment: I know the fractions but How to use them to get the combined fraction.It is NOT trivial.